# Grafana: set dashboard time range when choosing variable

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to somehow reset/override/define the time range based on choosing a variable in a dashboard?

I have a dashboard to show all kinds of data for events. The events are numbered and this is a variable in the dashboard so I can show the data for a particular event. However, events will have happened for let's say 2 hours on a specific date. 
So I find myself constantly resetting the date range and zooming in again on the charts when I change events. 
Is there a way to set this time when setting the variable?

Comment: Absolute or relative time range?

Comment: absolute. The events are numbered (the event number is what I use as variable in the dashboard). An event occured on a particular date on a given time. datapoints for the event are all timestamped, so the datetime information is available in the dataset

Comment: You will need to write own plugin for that or at least JS function, which will update time range.

Comment: @JanGaraj would you still need to write a plugin/js function if this time range was fixed / pre-defined? I.e., if you wanted to fix the absolute time range per dashboard (based on some data received from the query).

Answer (score 2):

My new plugin may be of use to you. I had a similar issue which I decided to make this solution for.

[image: Screenshot]

The buttons will set the timepicker's time range based on data from a datasource.

Enjoy!

https://github.com/WilliamVenner/grafana-timepicker-buttons